# UnsupportedOperationException in using a javafx SimpleMapProperty

Tags: java, javafx-2

Why does the following code throw `UnsupportedOperationException`?

```
import javafx.beans.property.MapProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleMapProperty;


public class TestMapProperty {
    static MapProperty<String, String> model = new SimpleMapProperty<String, String>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        model.put("blue", "green"); // exception thrown here
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:203)
    at javafx.beans.binding.MapExpression.put(MapExpression.java:277)
    at TestMapProperty.main(TestMapProperty.java:10)
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the full exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually want to create an instance of an observable map you should use

```
ObservableMap<String,String> model = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Pace is still valid, but if you want a Property and not only an ObservableMap, then this is not the correct code.

```
static MapProperty<String, String> model = new SimpleMapProperty<String, String>(FXCollections.observableHashMap());
```

will fit more. You still have to initialize the SimpleMapProperty with a new ObservableMap instance. The constructors without an initial Map of SimpleMapProperty won't create one for you. This is because you may choose your own implementation of an ObservableMap for backing the Property.